# Why is my answer wrong for $P(g/e)$?

Tags: probability

$P(g \mid e) = \frac{P(g \text{ and } e)}{P(g)}$. So why is $\frac{3}{4}$ the correct answer but not $\frac{1}{2}$.

[This picture shows the probability problem with my answer, and at the bottom in shows the correct answer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrNO2.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions.

Comment: Use Bayes theorem on the form $P(g\mid e) = \frac{P(e\mid g)P(g)}{P(e)}$. All of the factors on the right hand side are easy to compute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 even numbered green balls.